# Xdebug Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9000

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I used before Xdebug v2, but after last update I faced with Xdebug v3.0.0, I replaced all what needed by the update user [guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed)

I'm using Docker.

my debug conf

```
#xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.mode=debug

#xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.client_port=9000

xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

#xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.start_with_request=yes

#xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.discover_client_host=0

xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
#xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/r_xdebug.log
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

and what I get in log when try to execute any PHP script :

```
tail -f /var/log/xdebug.log
[888] Log opened at 2020-11-29 10:39:51.670762
[888] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
[888] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[888] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9000', connect: Cannot assign requested address.
[888] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[888] Log closed at 2020-11-29 10:39:57.515970
```

When I try to execute the URL in a browser PhpStorm does not start debugger, but I checked

```
lsof -i :9000 | grep LISTEN
```

listen port appeared when I click listening in PhpStorm.
My conf was sync `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug` -> Debug port 9000

What's wrong with my Xdebug config and what I need to do?

Comment: 1) Cleanup your Xdebug config: remove (or comment out ALL Xdebug v2 options). 2) `xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1` -- this is v2 value -- it does NOTHING in v3. 3) You are running this in Docker .. and Xdebug says: "Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000". Well -- Xdebug is correct and this will NOT work. You need to connect to your HOST IS (where PhpStorm is running) and NOT localhost (which is inside the docker container). Change `xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1` to use Xdebug v3 config (HINT: it's `xdebug.client_host`)

Comment: You need to capture `phpinfo()` output in a same way you are trying to debug (web browser or CLI) and check actual values in Xdebug section: are they show what you have set in php.ini or did you miss something. **P.S.** I'm not super sure .. but php.ini uses `;` as a comment and not `#` (unless both of them are accepted for the same)

Answer (score 36):

I was getting this log:

```
[28-May-2022 11:08:50 America/New_York] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

I found that using

```
xdebug.log_level=0
```

stopped the excess logs.

Comment: This works if your problem with this message is not 'Why isn't xdebug working?' but 'This is causing my tests to fail when I don't have my IDE's debugging enabled'. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

I just want to share how I migrated from 2.x to 3.x

```
;Xdebug 2.X
;xdebug.remote_enable=true
;xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
;
;xdebug.remote_autostart=1
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
;xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
;xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
;xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
;xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
;xdebug.remote_mode=req


;Xdebug 3.X
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.client_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp` -- you do not need this, at all. It does nothing for quite long time (if always) and was removed back in 2.9.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63209405/783119 2) `xdebug.remote_log` -- it's v2 only. V3 uses `xdebug.log` for that.

Comment: Also I think the port is no changed from 9000 to 9003 [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#Step-Debugging)

Comment: `xdebug.discover_client_host=1` solved my problem, make sure you read [DBG-E-NOCON](https://xdebug.org/docs/errors).

Answer (score 11):

Please, update your `xdebug` file to:

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

Comment: `xdebug.discover_client_host=1` solved my problem, make sure you read [DBG-E-NOCON](https://xdebug.org/docs/errors).

Comment: that also solved my problem

Comment: What do these lines mean?

Comment: thank you i had too many settings just ruining my life

Comment: Where's the `xdebug` file?

Comment: @Sam it depends of your configuration and php version. Try to run the following command and check if you can figure out: `php --info | grep xdebug.ini`. This assumes that you have it installed.

Comment: I have those lines and `xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM` additionally and this error message is logged all the time.